# Sagemaker LDA topic model - how to access the params of the trained model? Also is there a simple way to capture coherence

Tags: python, lda, amazon-sagemaker

I'm new to Sagemaker and am running some tests to measure the performance of NTM and LDA on AWS compared with LDA mallet and native Gensim LDA model.

I'm wanting to inspect the trained models on Sagemaker and look at stuff like what words have the highest contribution for each topic. And also to get a measure of model coherence.

I have been able to successfully get what words have the highest contribution for each topic for NTM on Sagemaker by downloading the output file untarring it and unzipping to expose 3 files params, symbol.json and meta.json.

However, when I try to do the same process for LDA, the untarred output file cannot be unzipped.

Maybe I'm missing something or should do something different for LDA compared with NTM but I have not been able to find any documentation on this. Also, anyone found a simple way to calculate model coherence?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SageMaker notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/scientific_details_of_algorithms/lda_topic_modeling/LDA-Science.ipynb), which dives into the scientific details of LDA, also demonstrates how to inspect the model artifacts. Specifically, how to obtain the estimates for the Dirichlet prior `alpha` and the topic-word distribution matrix `beta`. You can find the instructions in the section titled *"Inspecting the Trained Model"*. For convenience, I will reproduce the relevant code here:

```py
import tarfile
import mxnet as mx

# extract the tarball
tarflie_fname = FILENAME_PREFIX + 'model.tar.gz' # wherever the tarball is located
with tarfile.open(tarfile_fname) as tar:
    tar.extractall()

# obtain the model file (should be the only file starting with "model_")
model_list = [
    fname
    for fname in os.listdir(FILENAME_PREFIX)
    if fname.startswith('model_')
]
model_fname = model_list[0]

# load the contents of the model file into MXNet arrays
alpha, beta = mx.ndarray.load(model_fname)
```

That should get you the model data. Note that the topics, which are stored as rows of `beta`, are not presented in any particular order.

Comment: Thanks this works, quite a pain re: beta though, this makes interpretation of topics more difficult

Comment: out of interest where did you read that beta rows are not in any particular order?

Comment: I'm glad it works now! Regarding the interpretation of topics, in the language of LDA, a "topic" is just a probability distribution over the vocabulary. Some post-processing is required to apply meaning/labels to each of the topics. For example, some kind of semantic interpretation needs to be done to assign high probabilities of "{ball, game, play, kick}" to the a topic label of "sports". Topic labels are a subject of their own. As for your second question, I knew about the no-particular-ordering because I was one of the creators of SageMaker LDA. Happy to answer more questions!

Comment: Here is a paper (I'm sure one of many) on how to extract representative keywords from a text document. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.2359.pdf) Perhaps it can be used to solve the topic labeling problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems I couldn't be talking to a better person for this! I understand that one has to decide on topics manually,I have already been playing around with Gensim and mallet LDA. When I say interpretation, I mean like with mallet/Gensim LDA one can look into each topic and look at the contribution of each word. If you say rows in beta aren't ordered in sagemaker LDA how can I be sure which row is for which topic?

Comment: I better understand your question, now. Each row of the matrix `beta` is a topic: a probability distribution over the vocabulary. The 0th entry is the probability of word_0 occurring in that topic, the 1st entry is the probability of word_1 occurring in that topic, etc. If you `argsort` the probabilities in that row/topic you can find the words in the vocabulary that are most represented in that topic. Specifically, an `argsort` gives you the indexes of the words which you would then look up using your chosen embedding. (e.g. “cat” -> word_0, “dog” -> word_1, “bird” -> word_2, ...)

Comment: Sure I understand that but how do I know which row corresponds to which topic if the rows aren't ordered? So, for example, how do I know which row corresponds to topic 5? Logically I would say row 5 but it seems this may not be the case. Also, am I right in assuming that the order of columns in beta are the same as in the input matrix? Really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: The first row is "topic 1", the second row is "topic 2", etc. By "no particular order" I meant that there is no particular meaning to the order in which the topics are presented. The topics are just those that the algorithm found. I suppose the confusion can be cleared up with the following scenario: suppose you generated test data using a priori known topics. The LDA algorithm should discover those same topics. However, the rows of `beta` will be a permutation of the a priori topics. That is, the first row doesn't necessarily match with the first known topic. See the linked notebook example.

Comment: Hi Chris - is there an easy way to get the topic mixtures for the training set?

Comment: I don't believe they're computed during the training process so you would have to set up an inference endpoint. Alternately, I believe you can save the effort of spinning up a second instance by using SageMaker [batch transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-batch.html) but I haven't tried this, myself.

Comment: I figured this may be the case but wanted to double check. Thanks for getting back to me

Answer (score 0):

Regarding coherence, there's no default implementation in sagemaker AFAIK.

You can implement you own metric like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def calculate_coherence(topic_vectors):
    similarity_sum = 0.0
    num_combinations = 0
    for pair in combinations(topic_vectors, 2):
        similarity = cosine_similarity([pair[0]], [pair[1]])
        similarity_sum = similarity_sum + similarity
        num_combinations = num_combinations + 1
    return float(similarity_sum / num_combinations)
```

and get the coherence for your real model like:

```
print(calculate_coherence(beta.asnumpy()))
```

Some intuitive tests for coherence as follows:

```
predictions = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
               [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
               [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
               [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

assert calculate_coherence(predictions) == 0.0, "Expected incoherent"

predictions = [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
               [0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
               [0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
               [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

assert calculate_coherence(predictions) == 1.0, "Expected coherent"

predictions = [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
               [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
               [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
               [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
               [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
               [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
assert calculate_coherence(predictions) == 0.2, "Expected partially coherent"
```

Futher reading:

- http://svn.aksw.org/papers/2015/WSDM_Topic_Evaluation/public.pdf